# Unexpected Of Multi-Dimensional Arrays Behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having this problem with nested arrays; if I change the value of one array's element, the other array gets changed as well. I'm not sure if this is a bug or something expected in JS.

If you run this code, you'll get two console logs with arrays having first element as "Changed Value". I'm expecting to see "New Value" in the first array and "Changed Value" in valuesContainer_2 array.

```
    function validationProcess() {

    let valuesContainer_1 = [];
    let valuesContainer_2 = [];

    let data = [
        ["Option 1"],
        ["Option 2"],
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        valuesContainer_1.push(data[i]);
        valuesContainer_2.push(data[i]);
    }

    valuesContainer_1[0][0] = "New Value";
    console.log(valuesContainer_1);

    valuesContainer_2[0][0] = "Changed Value";
    console.log(valuesContainer_2);
}

    validationProcess();
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `data[i]` is an *object*, and objects get passed by reference, they're not copied unless you explicitly copy them

Comment: Can you please point out how objects can be copied? Do I need to create new objects, pass the data there and then push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want these to be independent arrays, you can push copies into your objects. [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is one way to do this. Note, however, that this is a shallow copy, if these array contain other arrays, those will still just be references to the original.

```js
function validationProcess() {

    let valuesContainer_1 = [];
    let valuesContainer_2 = [];

    let data = [
        ["Option 1"],
        ["Option 2"],
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        valuesContainer_1.push(data[i].slice()); //<-- add a copy
        valuesContainer_2.push(data[i].slice()); //<-- add a copy
    }

    valuesContainer_1[0][0] = "New Value";
    valuesContainer_2[0][0] = "Changed Value";

    console.log(valuesContainer_1);
    console.log(valuesContainer_2)
}

    validationProcess();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! What would be the best way to deep clone?

Comment: @Rehan To deep cloning takes a little work —  for a general solution, you need to loop over all the children and recursively copy. Some people do the shortcut with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[i]))` but you can usually do better that either if you can tailor a solution to your data rather than making a general solution. There should be lots of answers here on SO about deep copies.